# How to make color fill area between 2 points at HighCharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I would like to make color fill between 2 points at area chart by click. At this chart http://jsfiddle.net/nnqAb/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});

// button handler
$('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].data[3].update({
        y:150,
        marker:{
            fillColor: 'red',
        }
    }
   );

    chart.series[0].data[4].update({
        y:150,
        marker:{
            fillColor: 'red',
        }
    }
   );
});
```

});

by click at "May" point i want to get chart like this http://d.pr/i/7IcE It is possible to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes this is surely possible. we need to use 2 series of data.

in initail load the one will be with null data and the other will be wit normal data.

when click takes place give the second series some data so that it can show what you wanted to

like in here http://jsfiddle.net/nnqAb/3/

there is another approach to add a series when clicked on he button

```
chart.addSeries({
            data: [null,null,null, 150, 150, ],
                   color: 'red'
        });
```

updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/nnqAb/1/

Answer (score 1):

Yes! It's possible.

All you need is an area chart with aligning nulls in the series data:

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'area',
            }
            series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [null, null, 3, 3, 3, null, null, null] //when there's no "Jane" data, show "John" data
            }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 1, 3, null, 3, 1, 2, 8]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Full Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/adamb/RXLnQ/